# How to calculate the leading order solution to $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{[(x+n\epsilon)^2+1]^{3/2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, asymptotics, electromagnetism

I wish to calculate a series solution to the following sum,
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{[(x+n\epsilon)^2+1]^{3/2}},$$
where $x$, $\epsilon$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon \ll 1$.

Do you have any ideas for how I could do this?

My idea is to turn this infinite sum into an integral using the Fourier transform and then use an asymptotic method to evaluate this integral.

Here is what I have done so far.
Let
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{3/2}}.$$
Hence,
$$S(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x+n\epsilon).$$
Taking the Fourier transform (in the sense of distributions) gives
$$\hat{S}(\xi)=\hat{f}(\xi)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(i2n\pi\xi).$$
Let
$$w = \exp(i2\pi\xi).$$
Hence,
$$\hat{S}(\xi)=\hat{f}(\xi)\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{n=-N}^{N}w^n\right).$$
Using the Geometric series formula gives
$$\hat{S}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi)\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{w^{N+1}-w^{-N}}{w-1}\right).$$
Hence,
$$S(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(\xi)\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{w^{N+1}-w^{-N}}{w-1}\right)\exp(i2\pi\xi x)d\xi.$$
Now we have turned the infinite sum into an integral. Does this help? Do you know any asymptotic techniques that can be used to progress from here? Maybe Cauchy's integral theorem can be somehow used to deal with the $1/(w-1)$ factor?

For those curious, I am interested in $S$ because it gives the magnetic field along the axis of an infinite series of current loops (see [Field on Axis of Current Loop](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c3)).

Comment: I guess I'm just a little confused as to what your goal is. You already have a closed form for $S$ in the first line, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get a series solution of the form:
$$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^{\lambda+n}S_n(x).$$
I suspect we should find that $S_0(x)$ is a constant and $S_1(x)$ is of the form
$$S_1(x)~\cos(2\pi x/a).$$
Based on looking at graphs of S (see [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ufd0xnplrh))

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't 
$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{w^{N+1}-w^{-N}}{w-1} \right)
$$
divergent? Since $|w| = 1$, won't the terms in the numerator just bounce around the unit circle as $N\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Then what you want is a Fourier series and coincidentally the function has period $\epsilon$. Have you tried computing the Fourier coefficients $a_n = \int f(x) \cos (\omega x) dx$ directly yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series you want is a Fourier series

$$S(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s_n e^{in\omega x}$$

and we directly compute the coefficients of this series with its known formula. Over a period $\epsilon \implies \omega = \frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}$ we have

$$s_m = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{\frac{i2\pi m x}{\epsilon}}}{((x+n\epsilon)^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\:dx$$

Geometrically, consider the contribution from each shifted peak to the interval $[0,\epsilon]$ - they each contribute further and further, but continguous, sections of the tails of the function. Therefore by this reasoning (and the $\epsilon$-periodicity of the integrand) we can simplify this expression to

$$s_m = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\frac{i2\pi m x}{\epsilon}}}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx = \begin{cases}\frac{2}{\epsilon}\left|\frac{2\pi m}{\epsilon}\right|K_1\left(\left|\frac{2\pi m}{\epsilon}\right|\right) & m\neq 0 \\ s_0 = \frac{2}{\epsilon} & m = 0\end{cases}$$

where $K_n$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. Simplifying a bit and assuming $\epsilon > 0$ we get

$$S(x) = \frac{2}{\epsilon} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{8\pi n}{\epsilon^2}K_1\left(\frac{2\pi n}{\epsilon}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{\epsilon}\right)$$

the cosine Fourier series form.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Should it be
$$S(x)=\frac{2}{\epsilon}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8\pi n}{\epsilon^2}K_1\left(\frac{2\pi n}{\epsilon}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{\epsilon}\right)?$$

Comment: @Peanutlex almost, I have edited my post accordingly

Comment: Are you sure my expression above isn't correct? Do you mind double-checking?

Comment: @Peanutlex I have done more than that, why do you believe that is correct?

Comment: I think we need to replace 
$$K_1\left(\frac{2\pi m}{\epsilon}\right),$$
with
$$K_1\left(\frac{2\pi n}{\epsilon}\right).$$
I believe you should only have a factor 8 instead of 16 as your expression for $s_m$ has a factor 4.
Also, 
$$\cos\left(2\pi x/\epsilon\right),$$
should be 
$$\cos\left(2\pi n x/\epsilon\right)$$
otherwise, it's not a Fourier series.

Comment: @Peanutlex you were correct about the indices. However you should really double check your argument for the $8$, it is not correct.

Comment: I still think the factor should be 8 (see below).
$$\begin{aligned}
S(x) &= \frac{2}{\epsilon} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4\pi n}{\epsilon^2}K_1\left(\frac{2\pi n}{\epsilon}\right)\left[\exp\left(\frac{i2\pi n x}{\epsilon}\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{i2\pi n x}{\epsilon}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{2}{\epsilon} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8\pi n}{\epsilon^2}K_1\left(\frac{2\pi n}{\epsilon}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{\epsilon}\right),
\end{aligned}$$
using 
$$\exp(iz) + \exp(-iz) = 2\cos(z).$$

Comment: @Peanutlex yes you are right! I double double counted. I will fix.